# Show that a vectorfield is rotation free.

Tags: vector-analysis

So this is a very specific assignment. I Need to show that G is rotation free.

$F(x,y) = (P_F , Q_F) =( \frac{e^x(x\cos(y)+y\sin(y))-x}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{e^x(-x\cos(y)+y\sin(y))-y} {x^2+y^2} )$

$G(x,y) = (P_G , Q_G) =
\begin{cases}
    F(x,y)& \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
    (1,0)  &  \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0)\\  
\end{cases}$

I have already shown that $F(x,y)$ is rotation free, by showing.

$Rot(F) = \frac{\partial Q_F}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P_F}{\partial y} = 0$

But how do I show the same for $G(x,y)$ when it is a function seperated like so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calcuate the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial Q_G}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial P_G}{\partial y}$ using the definition of partial derivative.
$$\frac{\partial Q_G}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x_\to 0}\frac{Q_G(x,0)-Q_G(0,0)}x=\cdots$$
$$\cdots$$

Comment: But how does that help me get $\frac{\partial Q_G}{\partial x} (x,y)$ ?

Comment: @Nillo, the $_F$ was a typo, sorry.

Comment: yeah I could see that. It is more. If I have the derative in (0,0) how does that help me get the derative for the whole (x,y) ? What is the conection ?

Comment: @Nillo, in the open set $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, $G=F$, so $\text{rot }G=\text{rot }F$.

Comment: Okay so all I need to do is find the derative where F is not defined by using limit $x -> 0$.
But 
$ \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{ \cos(y)}{y} -  \frac{ \sin(y)}{y^2}$

$ \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0$

So $Rot(G) \neq 0 $ ?

Comment: @Nillo: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(x,0)$ is not the same thing as $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(0,0)$.  Use the difference quotient in the definition of partial derivative and take the limit.